Serialise `pdf-occur` buffer
Is it possible to serialise a live buffer like the pdf-occur buffer? Is there a builtin way of doing this. I've tried to save the buffer in the text file, then opened it and tried setting it to pdf-occur mode and set the variable pdf-occur-search-documents, didn't work.

What exactly are you trying to do? Why do you need to serialize the bufer?

It's to save the results of pdf-occur and make it persistent. A tad faster than rerunning the search on large pdf files, but I suppose it's not worth the effort. I just wondered whether there was a builtin method for that sort of thing. This is to do with my LaTeX question and its packages' options. I thought I could set up completing read for it that on accept takes me to the pdf bit of the option defintion/explanation.

The PDFOccur buffer uses text properties to store the information it needs to jump to the appopriate place in the file. You need to save the text properties. ISTR there is at least one question on this site, where a method to save text properties is shown (IIRC the method is described, with a link to code). Whether that will be enough, I don't know, but it seems to be the absolute minimum needed to allow the links to work. I'll try to find the question (though not tonight) - but I hope somebody will actually point it out, so I don't have to search :-)

See section File format conversion in the Elisp Reference manual for the building blocks of this.

Some ideas can be found at https://www.reddit.com/r/emacs/comments/1f8wxrg/making_text_property_changes_persistent/.

Perhaps this might help: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/51339/have-emacs-remember-text-properties-of-buffer - but I cannot find the reference I remember which was a package that provides text-property peristence, perhaps because the reference was added in a comment. [Later] something like this: https://github.com/mneilly/Emacs-Persistent-Overlays but for text-properties.

The first answer in that redit thread worked. Thank you very much!
